# How to retain values appended to a python list

Tags: python, list

Please I need help with this code.I want mylist to retain values appended to it next time the function 'no_repeat_rule' is called.  I'm pretty new to python. My code is below:

```
def no_repeat_rule(play_board):

    mylist = list()
    if seeds_left(play_board) == 2 and sum(play_board[:6])== 1:
        mylist.append(play_board)
        return mylist
```

Output of this code (in part) is:
...

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

Player 1 chose cup  0

[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

Player 2 chose cup 6

[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

...

what I want the function 'no_repeat_rule' to do is to grow mylist each time a player plays. I don't know if this is clear enough to get help?

Comment: I'm assuming play_board is a list?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do would be to add another parameter in the function defintion, such that it looks like:

```
def no_repeat_rule(play_board, aList):
```

Before you call the function, declare a list outside of the function. Set this equal to the result of the function, and pass it as a parameter whenever you call the function. For instance:

```
x = list()

def no_repeat_rule(play_board, aList):

    myList = aList
    if seeds_left(play_board) == 2 and sum(play_board[:6])== 1:
        myList.append(play_board)
        return myList

x = no_repeat_rule(someBoardHere, x)
```

I believe this should work if I understand what you're asking. If not, please respond and I'll try something else.

Comment: Don't name the parameter `list` please; that will shadow the `list` constructor. You could just name it `myList` in the first place after all (since as written, you immediately alias one to the other, so save the unnecessary and harmful `list` name).

Comment: @ShadowRanger yeah, that's a good point, I didn't even realize I did it haha. thanks for the tip

Comment: What's the point of `myList = aList`?  Why not just use `aList` throughout, since `myList` and `aList` will refer to the same list object anyway.

Comment: @cdarke that would work as well, this is just a bad habit i've picked up. the alias could be taken out and it work the same

Comment: @HunBurry I'm not sure your solution could work. You probably need to make aList global, otherwise, you are updating a local copy.

Comment: @HunBurry I'm grateful for your help, your idea worked. ShadowRanger thank you for the tip on using list constructor. I used myList throughout as suggested by cdarke, thanks everyone

Comment: @HunBurry on closer look, I found myList grew when each player played but the initial output is not retained.  Output of the code looks like:[[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
Player 2 chose cup 7

[[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
Player 1 chose cup 2

[[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]...

Comment: @Ola so all but the initial values are working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

what do you need is an object which is associated with the function. It calls attribute. It is very handy in python.

Your code may look like this:

```
def no_repeat_rule(play_board):
    if not hasattr(no_repeat_rule,"mylist"):
        no_repeat_rule.mylist = []
    if seeds_left(play_board) == 2 and sum(play_board[:6])== 1:
        no_repeat_rule.mylist.append(play_board)
        return no_repeat_rule.mylist
```

I couldn't check this code, but it should work for local atributes. BTW it is for python 2.7